# If I stream a file to s3, will the event trigger once the file is complete?

Tags: amazon-s3, streaming, amazon-sqs

As title says, if I attached an event to an S3 bucket for put events and I stream a file to that bucket, will the event trigger once the upload starts? That way a receiver can start downloading stream for that file.

Or will the event be triggered after the file has been completed uploading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with what you are contemplating:

- The event does not fire until the upload is finished.
- Writing objects into S3 is always an atomic operation.  The write either completes successfully, or it doesn't happen at all... and until it completes successfully, the object does not actually exist in the bucket.

If you are writing a new object into a bucket, authorized requests for the object will return a 404 error *at least* until the upload completes successfully.

If you are overwriting an existing object, authorized requests for the object will always return the *old* copy of the object, unchanged and undamaged, *at least* until the overwrite completes successfully.

Note the use of "at least until," above.

In all regions, <strike>except US-Standard (us-east-1)</strike> uploads of new objects are generally available immediately after the upload.  <strike>In US-Standard, there may sometimes be a brief delay.</strike> Formerly, the us-east-1 region of S3 (Northern Virginia, which was previously designated the "US Standard" region) did not offer immediate (read-after-write) consistency for new objects, but now it does.

However, there is a catch: the object must not have been requested before it was uploaded.  If it is, the consistency model breaks.¹

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides eventual consistency for read-after-write.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#Regions

In all regions, overwrites of existing objects may also encounter a brief delay (and delete objects may remain accessible for a brief time after deletion).

This *potential* delay is because of S3's eventual consistency model on some operations, as described above.  S3 does not guarantee all operations will be immediately visible, though for practical purposes, they almost always are.  What S3 *does* guarantee is that if your upload completes successfully, with a success response from S3, then your object *is* committed to the S3 backing store.

The above applies to `PUT` uploads, PUT/Copy, and multipart.

For these reasons, S3 cannot stream your file out to a consumer while the upload has not yet completed.

To do that requires a different solution (though S3 could of course be used as a permanent repository after the streaming is done).

---

¹*the consistency model breaks.*  Almost certainly, this indicates that a request arriving at S3 consults a replica of the bucket index, and if the index has no knowledge of whether an object exists, it consults a more authoritative version of the index.  If it still finds nothing, it locally "remembers" that the object doesn't exist, because that upstream lookup is a comparatively expensive operation --  thus it won't look upstream again on subsequent requests -- but once the creation of the new object propagates into the local index, the object would be available.  The same theory explains the eventual consistency of overwrites and deletes.

Comment: I'm struggling to find any information on exactly when the event fires for a PUT of a new object. Bearing in mind that the data may not be visible until some time after the write has completed, is the event fired at the end of the client write, or when the data is available for read? Would I just need to retry the read until it's there?

Comment: @fiddlesticks it is essentially immedately after the `200 OK` response is sent to the client.  If no object has never existed at this specific path, and you've never tried to do a `GET` or `HEAD` on this specific path, the object should be available simultaneously with the firing of the trigger.  If you are overwriting objects, then your safest bet is to enable bucket versioning, and then use the object version ID provided with the event, and deliberately ask for the new version by its key+version-id.  Are you having a problem, or just trying to avoid a potential problem?

Comment: @fiddlesticks also, thank you for bringing my attention back to this question.  I've updated some older information to reflect what is currently documented and observed in S3.

Comment: We have a Kinesis connector that saves records to S3 and then loads them into Redshift. I was looking into using a manifest file so the Redshift COPY command knows which files should be in S3 for loading. I was also considering whether to do the Redshift load via a lambda, as if the lamda is triggered once the S3 file is available then all is good. However, I've realised that because of the read-after-write consistency, neither of these is necessary: our connector does the S3 write before invoking the COPY, so the Redshift load process is guaranteed to see the S3 files.

Comment: Using a manifest file is fine if the Redshift load is async, but it requires a 2nd Kinesis stream to take the manifest, which doubles the latency. This seems to be a standard pattern that AWS has blogged about, but I thought using a Lambda would be simpler and faster. Turns out it's not needed, so keeping it simple.

Comment: Note that if you are using something like TnT drive to move files into your S3 bucket, it is NOT an atomic operation. Currently experiencing some pain with this when uploading large files (>10gb) in which we have processes trying to watch and download new files in the bucket. S3 WILL create a key for your file as it is partially uploaded.

Comment: @NateH06 the application must be doing something sketchy to cause that result.  S3 operations are always atomic, including multipart uploads.  Confirm with the bucket logs and/or bucket versioning.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I'd agree, it is doing something sketchy. But I am sure it's happening, I am watching it from the AWS S3 console. It appears as a 0 byte file (or key, if you're using their jargon) as soon as my upload starts. And using the AWS SDK to see if there's a file in that bucket returns that key, mid-upload. Tested on a 13gb file, it took 2-3 minutes for the file size in S3 to change to the 13gb from 0b, once my machine said it had finished the upload. Just beware, is all, this is an extreme corner case from a 3rd party, not from AWS itself.